# How to test Django model fields

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, python-unittest

I want to do unit tests for Django model fields:

```
  class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'animal'
        ordering = ['name']
```

My Test setUp looks like this:

```
class TestAnimalModel(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.animal = Animal.objects.create(name = 'TestAnimal')
        self.animal2 = Animal.objects.create(name = 123)
        self.animal3 = Animal.objects.create(name = 'TestAnimalWithTooManyCharacters')
```

animal2 and animal3 are created even though they shouldn't because animal2.name is int and animal3.name has more than 30 characters. 
How then do I test if name field has proper values? 
Is it normal that the object is created even though it has values that doesn't match Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> they shouldn't because `animal2.name` is `int`

A `CharField` will call `str(…)` on what is passed as value. This can sometimes have unintended side-effects. But Django fields are designed to accept a variety of values. For example for a `DateField`, it also accepts a date formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`. We can see this in the [implementation of a `CharField` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/forms/fields.py#L223-L231):

> ```
> class CharField(Field):
>     # …
>
>     def to_python(self, value):
>         """Return a string."""
>         if value not in self.empty_values:
>             value = str(value)
>             if self.strip:
>                 value = value.strip()
>         if value in self.empty_values:
>             return self.empty_value
>         return value
> ```

---

> `animal3.name` has more than 30 characters.

If I run this with MySQL I get a:

```
>>> Animal.objects.create(name='TestAnimalWithTooManyCharacters')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'name' at row 1")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1410, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'name' at row 1")
```

Depending on the database you use, it might (not) be accepted. SQLite for example does *not* enforce length constraints. Indeed, as the [*FAQ* of *SQLite* says](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html):

> **(9) What is the maximum size of a VARCHAR in SQLite?**
>
> **SQLite does not enforce the length of a `VARCHAR`**. You can declare a `VARCHAR(10)` and SQLite will be happy to store a 500-million character string there. And it will keep all 500-million characters intact. Your content is never truncated. SQLite understands the column type of "`VARCHAR(N)`" to be the same as "`TEXT`", regardless of the value of `N`.

So SQLite will not validate it.

You can let the Django validators run however *before* saving it to the database, for example with:

```
animal = Animal(name='TestAnimalWithTooManyCharacters')
animal.full_clean()
animal.save()
```

This will let the Django validators run and raise exceptions if the data is not valid:

```
>>> animal = Animal(name='TestAnimalWithTooManyCharacters')
>>> animal.full_clean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/django/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1238, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'name': ['Ensure this value has at most 30 characters (it has 31).']}
```

A Django `ModelForm` will also check this and reject the data passed to the form in case the string is too long.